# Error inserting pandas dataframe to MySQL using df.to_sql() function

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   driver_id value                       ts_1          created_ts
0          1    []        2021-11-18 11:00:00 2021-11-18 15:00:00
1          2    []        2021-11-18 15:00:00 2021-11-18 15:00:00
2          1    []        2021-11-18 12:00:00 2021-11-18 15:00:00
3          3    []  2021-11-18 12:00:00+01:00 2021-11-18 15:00:00
4          3   [5]  2021-11-18 06:00:00-08:00 2021-11-18 15:00:00
```

I have a helper function which is used to insert the dataframe data to MySQL server. Here is the code:

```
def add_to_mysql(self, df, table):
    engine = create_engine(self._engine_url)
    df.to_sql(table, con=engine, if_exists="append", index=False)
```

I am using python SQLAlchemy ORM to interact with MySQL. `df.to_sql` in the above helper function is throwing the below exception while inserting the dataframe:

```
E       sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (pymysql.err.ProgrammingError) (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '), '2021-11-17 07:00:00', '2021-11-17 11:00:00'),('2', (), '2021-11-17 11:00:00'' at line 1")
E       [SQL: INSERT INTO test_valuetypestringfloattrue_f96defa3_test_valuetypestringfloa (driver_id, value, ts_1, created_ts) VALUES (%(driver_id)s, %(value)s, %(ts_1)s, %(created_ts)s)]
E       [parameters: ({'driver_id': '1', 'value': [], 'ts_1': Timestamp('2021-11-17 07:00:00'), 'created_ts': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 17, 11, 0)}, {'driver_id': '2', 'value': [], 'ts_1': Timestamp('2021-11-17 11:00:00'), 'created_ts': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 17, 11, 0)}, {'driver_id': '1', 'value': [], 'ts_1': Timestamp('2021-11-17 08:00:00'), 'created_ts': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 17, 11, 0)}, {'driver_id': '3', 'value': [], 'ts_1': Timestamp('2021-11-17 08:00:00+0100', tz='Europe/Berlin'), 'created_ts': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 17, 11, 0)}, {'driver_id': '3', 'value': [5.0], 'ts_1': Timestamp('2021-11-17 02:00:00-0800', tz='US/Pacific'), 'created_ts': datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 17, 11, 0)})]
E       (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/f405)

../../39feastenv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pymysql/err.py:143: ProgrammingError
```

I tried manually inserting the row in MySQL and found list [] and datetime.datetime() is causing the issue.

Is there any other method or library which can be used instead of `to_sql()` to handle this ? Or, we need to transform the columns before calling `to_sql()` ?

Comment: Can you post the sql table structure